# BITS Uploads in IIS over HTTPS

Tags: iis, https, microsoft-bits

I'm curious as to whether there are any known problems with trying to run the BITS Uploads extension on a web server running over HTTPS.

I have an extension set up, with the BITS-Sessions sub-folder automatically created. If I try and upload a file from my local PC using this:

bitsadmin /reset
bitsadmin /create /upload info_request
bitsadmin /setproxysettings info_request PRECONFIG
bitsadmin /addfile info_request https://[removed web server]/ C:\text.txt
bitsadmin /resume info_request

Which responds with:

ERROR CODE:    0x8020001b
ERROR CONTEXT: 0x00000005

However, the log on the web server seems to think everything was OK:

2015-05-26 08:57:48 [removed IP] BITS_POST / - 443 - [removed IP] Microsoft+BITS/7.5 - 200 0 0 1825

Could this be a HTTPS issue, or am I looking down the wrong road?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this was caused by a certificate error. Setting bitsadmin to ignore certificate errors allowed the file to be sent, whilst the certificate itself is investigated.